# Instagram API access taken

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I am completely new to programming. I am studying my masters in architecture in  London and I'm trying to extract data sets from instagram (filters used, location points, user etc) for my research in London.

I have tried with the intragram api but keep hitting a wall. I have a client ID and when I try get my access token, I get the following message:

{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

I have disabled my Disable implicit OAuth.

Any ideas?

Tom

Comment: what is the value of `redirect_uri` in the code and what is the value did u enter in instagram developer website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make a correct way to request CODE. use this url and replace with your correct information

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=YOUR-REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

Your redirection-uri are in:
[Your APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpRtB.png)

After your obtain a CODE

```
http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE
```